# Monitor printing of pdf files

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, printing, monitoring

So I have to create a console application that prints PDF files. Since I cannot use non-free libraries to print PDF, and I found out that most of free libraries for printing PDF files in .NET use a code similar to this

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.Verb = "Print";
info.FileName = fileName;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = info;
process.Start();
```

I use this code to start the printing process.
My problem is that I need to monitor the printing in case of an error occuring.
I've been searching for many days but I didn't find anything that works for me, since I can't use WMI (printer driver does not report its status to the spooler), I can't use PrintSystemJobInfo and PrintJobInfoCollection (I found out that it works with files natively handled by .NET but not PDF files), so the only thing that seems to work for now is to manage the printing with PrintQueue.

Now I'm looking for the proper way to use it, what I'm doing now is entering a while loop when the PrintQueueStatus is going from "None" to "Printing", and leaving the loop when the status goes to "Printing to "None", like this :

```
bool isCompleted = false;
bool isPrinting = false;

while (!isCompleted)
{
    _printQueue.Refresh();

    switch (_printQueue.QueueStatus)
    {
        [...]
        case PrintQueueStatus.None:
            Console.WriteLine("L'état n'est pas spécifié");
            if (isPrinting)
            {
                isPrinting = false;
                isCompleted = true;
            }
            break;
        [...]
        case PrintQueueStatus.Printing:
            Console.WriteLine("Le périphérique imprime");
            isPrinting = true;
            break;
        [...]
    }
}
```

This doesn't allow me to check easily every case of the PrintQueueStatus...
I thought of using events, but since I'm a beginner in .NET and I'm not familiar with events, and can't find how to do it.

So the question is mainly, is it possible to use events to monitor a change in the PrintQueueStatus and how to do it. If it's not possible, how can I do to monitor the printing.

Thanks.